# Python Selenium send_keys() error cause of the blank area inside the text file

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am in a interesting situation here.
I'm trying to automate a process for my Instagram account, when someone is following me, to send him a direct message for saying something like "Thank you". In this text is contained also emojis. So I was trying to make it work with emojis and after I finally make it work, I find out that the `.send_keys()` when is trying to send the text from my .txt file doesn't working properly cause of the blank areas inside of it. For example let's say that I'm having this text inside:

```
My name is Bill 

I'm 22
```

This will not work cause of the blank area between them. But if i write them in a row like this `My name is Bill  I'm 22` is working totally fine.
So my issue is this. I want it to make it work like the first example. Can anyone help me with my problem here?

Here is the code I have wrote for the text:

```
with open(path + '\\text.txt', encoding='utf-8') as t_f:
        txt = t_f.read()

#Here is the element for typing my message
text_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea""")

#Here it processing the 'txt' to be able to have emojis
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '{}'".format(txt),text_element)
text_element .send_keys('.')
text_element .send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in instagram , facebook etc "\n" is end of string . you have to use enter + shift instead.

when you have multiple line , its actually ending with '\n'

so use something like:

```
text_element.click()

for part in txt.split('\n'):
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    action.send_keys(part)
    action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(
        Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

Comment: I have tried something very similar with ```ActionChains``` but I don't know what I do wrong. Your solution worked perfectly. THANK YOU A LOT man !!!!!